# dealloc after instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, release, dealloc

i have a problem:

```
ExploreViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];
vc.id_from = post.user_id;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

As you can see, i instantiate the viewController and push it into navigationController.
vc, should be **autorelease** , but dealloc method is never called.

So, if i **release** the view controller after pushed it:

```
ExploreViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileViewController"];
vc.id_from = post.user_id;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

dealloc method is called when i pop the view controller, but if i execute again the code above, dealloc is immediately called and app crash because others objects don't found vc.

So, if i don't release it, the memory is increasingly busy.

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not released because when you:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

The `UINavigationController` has a reference to the `vc`. So basically you have 2 references to it:

```
self.navigationController + ExploreViewController *vc = 2
```

At the end of the method you have one:

```
self.navigationController = 1
```

Once you pop the `vc` from the `UINavigationController`, the `vc` should be released and the `dealloc` method called. Another thing, you shouldn't call `release` on object you don't own. In this case `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` returns an auto-release object.

Answer (score 1):

You should only call `release` on objects after alloc, new or copy. In this case, you should not call `[vc release].`